# Integer variable treated as categorical in AutoViz

Tags: python-3.10

I have a column on a pandas data frame that has only integers between 1 and 8. Originally the column was of type int64.

When I run AutoViz on the data frame, it considers the column as a categorical column, instead of numerical. This changes the graphics displayed by the package.

I found a solved issue at their github repo, and applied the suggested solution (convert the column from int64 to float). The problem persists.

```
    count_stops_by_carga.dtypes
    >>> Número Carga       object
    >>> CPF Motoristas     object
    >>> cnpj start        float64
    >>> cnpj end          float64
    >>> stops             float64
    >>> dtype: object
    
    dft_carga = AV.AutoViz(
        filename="",
        dfte=count_stops_by_carga,
        verbose=1,
        lowess=True,
        chart_format="bokeh",
        max_rows_analyzed=150000,
        max_cols_analyzed=30
    )
    
    >>> [Resulting graph with the issue][1]
```